# What is the best way to SELECT from and TRUNCATE an InnoDB table in one atomic operation?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, innodb, atomic

I want to read from an InnoDB table using SELECT and then truncate it using TRUNCATE in one operation such that other queries have to wait for the TRUNCATE operation to complete before they can modify the table. What is the best way to do that? From what I understand, table locks don't work with TRUNCATE. But from my tests, transactions *do* work with TRUNCATE. However transactions are only guaranteed not to overlap if the isolation level is SERIALIZABLE.

I am using PHP and MySQLi. The default isolation level is REPEATABLE READ so I am changing it to SERIALIZABLE to prevent concurrent queries from modifying the table before the transaction completes:

```
$mysqli->query("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE");

$mysqli->begin_transaction();

// Select statements reading from `my_table`

$mysqli->query("TRUNCATE `my_table`");

$mysqli->commit();
```

This seems to be working just fine. I'm just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have error reporting switched on:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

You can use transactions to read and delete the data in one step. I am not sure why you have set different isolation mode, but I assume you don't need it. If I understand it correctly it will lock the rows and prevent deletion.

You can't use `TRUNCATE` because it is a DDL statement and it does not work with transactions. `DELETE` is slower, but it can be rolled back.

```
try {
    // Start transaction
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
    $mysqli->query('DELETE * FROM my_table');

    // Commit changes
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // Something went wrong. Rollback
    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GET_LOCK()` and `RELEASE_LOCK()` are orthogonal to transactions, etc.  (They are extremely rarely used, but your case may need them.)